# Email alert after threshold crossed, logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, statsd, riemann

I am using `logstash`, `elasticsearch` and `kibana` to analyze my logs. 
I am alerting via email when a particular string comes into the log via `email` output in logstash:

```
email {
        match => [ "Session Detected", "logline,*Session closed*" ]
...........................
}
```

This works fine.

Now, I want to alert on the count of a field (**when a threshold is crossed**):

Eg If `user` is field, I want to alert when number of **unique users** go more than 5.

Can this be done via `email` output in logstash??
Please help.

**EDIT:**
As @Alcanzar told I did this:

**config file:**

```
    if [server] == "Server2" and [logtype] == "ABClog" {

        grok{
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:server-name} abc\[%{INT:id}\]:
 \(%{USERNAME:user}\) CMD \(%{GREEDYDATA:command}\)"]       
        }   

        metrics {
                meter =>  ["%{user}"]
                add_tag =>  "metric"
            }   

        }
```

So according to above, for `server2` and `abclog` I have a grok pattern for parsing my file and on the `user` field parsed by grok I want the **metric** applied.

I did that in the config file as above, but I get strange behaviour when I check logstash console with `-vv`.

So if there are 9 log lines in the file it parses the 9 first, after that it starts metric part but there the `message` field is not the **logline** in the log file but it's the user-name of my PC, thus it gives `_grokparsefailure`. Something like this:

```
 output received {
   :event=>{"@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2014-06-17T10:21:06.980Z", "message"=>"my-pc-name", 
    "root.count"=>2, "root.rate_1m"=>0.0, "root.rate_5m"=>0.0, "root.rate_15m"=>0.0, 
    "abc.count"=>2, "abc.rate_1m"=>0.0, "abc.rate_5m"=>0.0, "abc.rate_15m"=>0.0, "tags"=>["metric", 
    "_grokparsefailure"]}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"137"
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you found a proper solution, can you please share it with otheres

Comment: @TzookBarNoy: I could not get a proper solution via metrics so I tried riemann alerting tool (http://riemann.io/) and did it using that.

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you need is http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/metrics.

You'd want to use a `metrics` tag to calculate the rate of your event, and then use the `thing.rate_1m` or `thing.rate_5m` in an `if` statement around your email output.

For example:

```
filter {
  if [message] =~ /whatever_message_you_want/ {
    metrics {
        meter =>  "user"
        add_tag =>  "metric"
    }
  }
}

output {
  if "metric" in [tags] and [user.rate_1m] > 1 {
   email { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer above will count the number of users, but I want to alert when number of UNIQUE users (as in question) threshold is crossed. Can that be done??

Comment: If you to measure the rate of unique users, you are going to need to create a custom filter for that that conforms to your situation since none of the pre-exsting filters will do exactly what you want.  There is a throttle filter that might help you, but it seems like your requirements don't fit what logstash can do out of the box.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks. Any idea about the issue mentioned in the edit??

Comment: if you are talking about the _grokparsefailure, just add an `if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] { drop {} }` right after the grok

Comment: I am talking about, the message field which is equal to logline when it parses through grok filter but when it comes to metric filter the message field is equal to my-pc-name (as shown in the question)Thus it gives a grokparsefailure as it does not find user field inside message. Why this behaviour??

Comment: you are getting the grokparsefailure because the event doesn't match your pattern... try putting in the drop{} that i mention above and it'll ignore those lines that don't match your grok

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating on the logstash side is fairly limited. It also increases the state size thus memory consumption may grow. Alerts that run on the Elasticsearch layer offer more freedom and possibilities.

Logz.io alerts on top of ELK are offered in the below blog: http://logz.io/blog/introducing-alerts-for-elk/